# Pushing data from pig to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-pig

I wrote a small script to push data to elasticsearch:

```
REGISTER /path/to/elasticsearch-hadoop-1.0.0.jar;
DEFINE ESStorage org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.ESStorage('es.resource=sample/');
data = load 'somelog.log' using PigStorage('\n'); 
B = foreach data generate $0 as id;
STORE B INTO 'sample' USING ESStorage('es.http.timeout = 5m ; es.index.auto.create = false');
```

I am getting the following error when running the pig script from the command line:

```
 pig -Dpig.additional.jars=/path/to/elasticsearch-hadoop-1.0.0.jar script.pig 

Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.ESStorage using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:653)
at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1257)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured that one by myself, needed ESStorage class (it was not part of elasticsearch-hadoop-1.0.0.jar)

So I got, REGISTER 'elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar'
from `git clone https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop`
then I ran gradle to build the jars and used elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
in the pig script.

Answer (score 0):

```
REGISTER /path/to/elasticsearch-hadoop-1.0.0.jar;
```

shall point to a correct path

Like `REGISTER /opt/elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.M1/dist/elasticsearch-hadoop-1.3.0.M1-yarn.jar`

You can then run them with:

```
pig -f script.pig
```